# Explode Dataset column on many rows doesn't work in a loop

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, explode

I am trying to explode one column in many rows on a Java Spark Job. 
When I do the explode on just one column it works well, but if i try to loop on all my columns to do the explode, it doesn't work.

### Here is my code :

Doesn't work :

```
    for (String column : columns) {
        tableDS = tableDS .withColumn(column, explode(split(column(column), "\\|")));
    }
```

No exceptions. it returns just the only line where there is no content to be splitted (null column values).

Works only on the given column :

```
    for (String column : columns) {
        tableDS = tableDS .withColumn("column1", explode(split(column("column1"), "\\|")));
    }
```

Do you have an idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: You should probably explain how exactly it doesn't work: error, exception, just doesn't do anything, etc.

Comment: No exceptions. The result is just the last line (only line where there is no column  content to be splitted).

Comment: question edited accordingly

Comment: I found out what was the issue.
In fact when the explode processes columns that have null values the split will fail but no exception will be thrown. So the lines with null columns will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the issue. In fact when the explode processes columns that have null values the split will fail but no exception will be thrown. So the lines with null columns will be discarded.